# Error al usar AlarmManager y BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio

El objetivo es que al cabo de x tiempo, en este caso 10s, comiense a ponerme en modo vibración la llamada proveniente del numero x. Cuando no llamo al método iniciarProceso(), todo funciona bien OK. Pero cuando lo llamo me aparece este error en el Logcat:

```
02-22 21:05:49.982 5787-5787/com.example.andry.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 5787
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.andry.myapplication.Call_Reciver: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2580)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.andry.myapplication.Call_Reciver.onReceive(Call_Reciver.java:19)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Esta es la parte donde llamo al método iniciarProceso():

```
  boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            iniciarProceso();
         }
     });
```

Método iniciarProceso():

```
public void iniciarProceso(){
int i=10;
Intent intent= new Intent(this,Call_Reciver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(i*1000),pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this,"La funcion inicia dentro de 10s",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

Y por ultimo este es el método de la clase Call_Reciver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      AudioManager am=(AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        String incomingnumber=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if (incomingnumber.equals("unNumeroCualquiera")){
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }

    }
 }
```

Este es mi Manifest:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andry.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
         <activity android:name=".Activity_llamadas">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
             <receiver android:name=".Call_Reciver">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">
            </action>
         </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>`

La linea 19 de la clase Call_Reciver es esta: `if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema que se muestra en el LogCat,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.example.andry.myapplication.Call_Reciver:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.andry.myapplication.Call_Reciver.onReceive(Call_Reciver.java:19)

**Es debido a que el `Intent` que obtienes en el método `onReceive()` no tiene el valor que intentas obtener** (key: `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE`) :

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         ...      
         intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
         ...

         }
```

y esto es debido a que **no estas enviando este valor en el `intent` que creas en `iniciarProceso()`**, debes agregar el valor que será recibido en la clase `Call_Reciver`:

```
public void iniciarProceso(){
int i=10;
Intent intent= new Intent(this,Call_Reciver.class);

/*Agregar valor en intent que será recibido en Call_Reciver.class*/
intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, "AQUI AGREGA EL VALOR");

PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(i*1000),pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this,"La funcion inicia dentro de 10s",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Muy bien me funciono..Solo que quiero que me empiece a poner las llamadas entrantes en vibración, a los 10s una ves apretado el botón, PERO, me las pone en vibración sin haber apretado el botón, o sea entra en vibración una ves instalado la app. Ya probé escribiendo en el LogCat para comprobar si entraba a los 10s al método onRecive, Y, SI, FUNCIONO..Entonces, no entiendo? Como hago para que funcione solo después de X tiempo y no cuando se instala la app..Alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -negativo, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicarlo.

Comment: Y respecto al comentario que te hice, alguna idea???

Answer (score 1):

si quieres que vibre tienes que ponerlo en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Si, gracias por la sugerencia, eso ya lo tenia puesto, solo que no me había percatado de que no había salido en la pregunta..Alguna otra idea??

Comment: El error no es de permisos es un java.lang.NullPointerException